# Can one stop "semantic ui" from writing info to the console?

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

Using semantic-ui: http://semantic-ui.com/

It writes all kinds of info to the console, not just when an error occurs.

Is there an easy way to stop it from communicating with the console?

I am writing a laboratory page for an Ajax API, and developers will look at their console on my page to see what's going on when some Ajax calls are made. I don't want to see un-related messages about semantic-ui from the semantic-ui framework.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn off debug mode for modules you don't need debug. Example for module 'modal' below.

There are 2 ways:

1) Set default value for module. Place it at the start of your script (before usage of module):

```
$.fn.modal.settings.debug = false;
```

2) Set value for each case of module usage:

```
$('.modal').modal({'debug': false});
```

The same for every other semantic-ui module such as popup etc.